# `Highway.forward: input must be present` in ELMo embedding?

Tags: python, nlp, embedding, word-embedding, elmo

I use [Elmo Embeddings](https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/2020/01/31/elmo.html) for my NLP task. The *pretrain* was in the Indonesian language from [this git](https://github.com/HIT-SCIR/ELMoForManyLangs). Importing the library by using the syntax

`from elmoformanylangs import Embedder`

causing the following error:

`TypeError: Highway.forward: input must be present`

Please help me to understand what the error message means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but this refers to the unimplemented superclass method (forward) in `torch.nn.Module`. This class has the following definiton.

`forward: Callable[..., Any] = _forward_unimplemented`

If you scroll down a bit you will see the definiton of _forward_unimplemented:

```
def _forward_unimplemented(self, *input: Any) -> None:
```

The Highway forward definiton has to match this signature too, therefore you will need a `*input` argument too.
I got my Hungarian version working with the following signature and first line, probably this could help you too.

```
    def forward(self, *input: torch.Tensor) -> type(None): #pylint: disable=arguments-differ
    current_input = input[0]
```

I just edited my \elmoformanylangs\modules\highway.py file under the site-packages of my python environment, and got it working.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do you know how to fit the vectors of this elmo to bilstm? @nata108

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
pip uninstall overrides
pip install overrides==3.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was due to an unsupported version of `overrides`.

You can always install the appropriate version, if you are working with anaconda, through `conda install overrides==no.version`.